# Sharepoint Lists not saving data

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

i have a form which has a button "SAVE" on clicking the save button data in the respective fields has to be store in sharepoint list and should should redirect to the other page
but when i click save button it only redirects me to the other page and does not store data in sharepoint list

what type of error it may be.... running redirecting code but not running saving code?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but, are you absolutely sure nothing gets saved? You may be redirected to a view that has been configured to exclude items that match the once you have tried to save.

Comment: well if i am restricted to view will it not allow me to get  data from list and show it in a grid?... because in this case when i save data it transfer to a sharepoint list and then transfer to the other page and that page gets the data from the list which is not getting

Comment: I’m not sure I follow what you mean by transfer but it sounds like you are navigated back to a page or similar rather than the view all items view within the list. I would double check the view settings of the grid you expect the new item to appear in to see if there’s any filters that may filter out your new items. I would also navigate to the list itself, using the view all site content link in the site actions menu to see if you can find your items using one of the other views.
Has the list been customized in any way, like event receivers, a workflow or similar?

Comment: If there is a session timeout between opening the page and clicking the Save button, then the entered data may be lost. Does it happen also if you click Save shortly after opening the page?